# Using the phone's built in sensors in Android

Tags: android

I am creating an app where I will send the data I receive from the Android phones sensors, to another Android phone using Wifi-Direct.

I am able to get the values of the sensors by writing the code in a class that extends Activity. I have used the Sensor Manager Class.

But now I want to get the sensor values in a Background thread. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` event inside of an `Async_Task` which is great for background threads.

When the event fires inside of your `Async_Task`, unregister your sensor listener and then re-register it. The screen will continue to stay off, but the monitoring will continue.

Here is a relevant article and good code [example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/04/monitoring-sensors-in-background.html) on this blog

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on Google

Comment: Part B, Step 2 has some useful code snippets - [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-barometer-logger-acquiring-sensor-data/)